# Page number does not appear on first page of table of contents, list of figures and list of tables

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, fancyhdr

When I do my table of contents (TOC), my list of figures (LOF) and my list of tables (LOT), something strange happens, only the numbering of the page appears from the second page of the table of contents and what I want is that the page number in the bottom center of the first page of the table of contents appears and in the same way with the list of figures and the list of tables.

Here's a MWE :

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside,a4paper ]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}%centrar formulas
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}%Para poner fórmulas químicas
\usepackage{subfigure} % subfiguras
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs} %Para tablas importadas de excel
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}%row color
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float} %Para dejar fija la tabla 
%\usepackage{longtable} %Tabla en dos páginas
\usepackage{stackrel}
%\usepackage{enumerate} 
\usepackage{upgreek}%Para poner letras griegas en negrita
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{subfigure} % subfiguras%Para imágenes seguidas
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[myheadings]{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig, setspace, booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{fourier}
%\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{setspace} %interlineados
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumerate} % enumerados
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{algorithm}%Escribir algoritmos
\usepackage{algorithmic}%Escribir algoritmos
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
%\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{roman}
%\spacing{1.5}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}} 
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{Figura }
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Tabla }
\author{Alex Pozo}
\parindent= 0mm %Elimina la sangria
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contenido}
\renewcommand{\partname}{Parte}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Apéndice}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{ÍNDICE GENERAL}
\renewcommand*\bibname{REFERENCIAS BIBLIOGRÁFICAS}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexos}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anexos}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anexos}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % para que ponga subsubsecciones en el indice
\providecommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\providecommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}
%------------------------------------------------
\def\upint{\mathchoice%
    {\mkern3mu\overline{\vphantom{\intop}\mkern7mu}\mkern-20mu}%
    {\mkern7mu\overline{\vphantom{\intop}\mkern7mu}\mkern-14mu}%
    {\mkern7mu\overline{\vphantom{\intop}\mkern7mu}\mkern-14mu}%
    {\mkern7mu\overline{\vphantom{\intop}\mkern7mu}\mkern-14mu}%
  \int}
\def\lowint{\mkern3mu\underline{\vphantom{\intop}\mkern7mu}\mkern-10mu\int}
%------------------------------------------------
\lhead[]{}
\chead[]{}
\rhead[]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lfoot[]{}
\cfoot[]{}
\rfoot[]{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead[]{}
\chead[]{}
\rhead[]{}
\lfoot[]{}
\cfoot[]{ \bfseries \thepage}
\rfoot[]{}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{defi}{Definición}[chapter]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposición}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lem}{{ Lema }}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{{ Teorema }}[chapter]
\author{Alex Pozo}

\title{MODELIZACIÓN MATEMÁTICA DE TIEMPOS DE VIAJE DE LA TRONCAL CENTRAL TROLEBÚS.}
\setlength\parindent{2em }
\newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}
\onehalfspacing
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}

\begin{document}
%CARÁTULA

%\pagestyle{empty}%Para eliminar encabezados y pies de pagina
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contenido}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Referencias Bibliográficas}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contenido}
%\newcommand{\defeq}{\mathrel{\mathop:}=}
%------------------------
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
{
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{UCE-logo.jpg}
\label{fig:mesh1}
\end{figure}
\vspace{1.3cm}
{\LARGE {UNIVERSIDAD CENTRAL DEL ECUADOR} }\\[0.9cm]
{ \large{FACULTAD DE INGENIERÍA, CIENCIAS FÍSICAS Y MATEMÁTICA}}\\[0.4cm]
{\large {CARRERA DE INGENIERÍA MATEMÁTICA} }\\[1.8cm]
%{\textbf {CARRERA DE INGENIERÍA MATEMÁTICA} }\\[3.5cm]
{\Large{Modelización matemática de tiempos de viaje de la Troncal Central Trolebús}}%ODELIZACIÓN MATEMÁTICA DE TIEMPOS DE VIAJE DE LA TRONCAL CENTRAL TROLEBÚS }
\\[0.9cm]
{ {Trabajo de titulación, modalidad Proyecto de Investigación previo a la obtención del Título de
Ingeniero Matemático.
 }}\\[1.3cm]%\\Título de Ingeniero Matemático}}\\[1.3cm]
\raggedright{\Large AUTOR: Pozo Valdiviezo Alex Eduardo}\\[1.3cm]
\raggedright{\Large TUTOR: Dr. Hernán Benalcázar Gómez, Ph.D.}\\[1.5cm]
{Quito, 2018}
}
\end{center}
\newpage
%\chapter*{}
 % si no queremos que añada la palabra "Capitulo"
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Derechos de Autor} % si queremos que aparezca en el índice
%5\markboth{}{} % encabezado
%\vspace{-3cm}
\begin{center}
{
{ \LARGE{\textbf {DERECHOS DE AUTOR} }}\\[1cm]
}
\end{center}
%{\LARGE {UNIVERSIDAD CENTRAL DEL ECUADOR} }\\[0.9cm]
\sloppy Yo, Alex Eduardo Pozo Valdiviezo en calidad de autor y titular de los derechos morales y patrimoniales del trabajo de titulación: MODELIZACIÓN MATEMÁTICA DE TIEMPOS DE VIAJE DE LA TRONCAL CENTRAL TROLEBÚS, modalidad Proyecto de Investigación, de conformidad con el Art. 144 del CÓDIGO ORGÁNICO DE LA ECONOMÍA SOCIAL DE LOS CONOCIMIENTOS, CREATIVIDAD E INNOVACIÓN, concedo a favor de la Universidad Central del Ecuador una licencia gratuita, intransferible y no exclusiva para el uso no comercial de la obra, con fines estrictamente académicos. Conservo a mi favor todos los derechos de autor sobre la obra, establecidos en la normativa citada.\\
Así mismo, autorizo a la Universidad Central del Ecuador para que realice la digitalización y publicación de este trabajo de titulación en el repositorio virtual, de conformidad a lo dispuesto en el Art. 144 de la Ley Orgánica de Educación Superior.\\
El autor declara que la obra objeto de la presente autorización es original en su forma de expresión y no infringe el derecho de autor de terceros, asumiendo la responsabilidad por cualquier reclamación que pudiera presentarse por esta causa y librando a la Universidad de toda responsabilidad.\\[3cm]
\\
Firma:.........................................\\
Alex Eduardo Pozo Valdiviezo\\
CI: 1722586250\\
%Telf: 0984701216\\
Dirección electrónica: aepozov@uce.edu.ec
%E-mail: aepozov@uce.edu.ec
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Aprobación del Tutor}

%Quito, 12 de diciembre de 2018\par


\vspace{\baselineskip}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\begin{center}
{ \LARGE{\textbf {APROBACIÓN DEL TUTOR} }}\\[1cm]

\end{center}\par


%\vspace{\baselineskip}

%\vspace{\baselineskip}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\noindent En mi calidad de Tutor de Titulación, presentado por \textbf{ALEX EDUARDO POZO VALDIVIEZO}, para optar por el Grado de Ingeniero Matemático; cuyo título es MODELIZACIÓN MATEMÁTICA DE TIEMPOS DE VIAJE DE LA TRONCAL CENTRAL TROLEBÚS, considero que dicho trabajo reúne los requisitos y méritos suficientes para ser sometido a la presentación pública y evaluación por parte del tribunal examinador que se designe.%Yo, Guillermo En Hernán Benalcázar Gómez, Ph.D., en calidad de tutor del trabajo de investigación titulado MODELIZACIÓN MATEMÁTICA DE TIEMPOS DE VIAJE DE LA TRONCAL CENTRAL TROLEBÚS; elaborado por el señor Alex Eduardo Pozo Valdiviezo, estudiante de la Carrera de Ingeniería Matemática, Facultad de Ingeniería Ciencias Físicas y Matemática de la Universidad Central del Ecuador; considero que ha cumplido con los requisitos necesarios propuestos en su proyecto de investigación, por lo que apruebo su trabajo desarrollado. Con este antecedente, su tesis podrá ser habilitada para continuar con el proceso de titulación determinado por el Reglamento de Titulación de la Universidad Central del Ecuador.\par
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\noindent En la ciudad de Quito, a los 12 días del mes de diciembre de 2018.
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\noindent Dr. Hernán Benalcázar Gómez, Ph.D.\par

\noindent DOCENTE-TUTOR\par

\noindent C.C: \par


\vspace{\baselineskip}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

%\includepdf[pages={2}]{OFICIOS APROBACION TUTOR.pdf}
\newpage

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DEDICATORIA
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\pagestyle{empty}
%\frontmatter


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedicatoria}
\begin{flushright}
\textit{DEDICATORIA}
\begin{flushright}
\textit{A \\
mis padres,\\
Bella y Fabián,\\
 pilares fundamentales \\en mi vida, \\
y me alientan en cada \\ proyecto.}
\end{flushright}
\begin{flushright}
\textit{Politics is for the present, \\
 but an equation is for eternity.\\
 Albert Einstein}
\end{flushright}
\end{flushright}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AGRADECIMIENTOS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Agradecimientos}
%\pagenumbering{roman}
%\setcounter{page}{5}

%\chapter*{}
\begin{center}
{
{ \LARGE{\textbf {AGRADECIMIENTOS}}}
}
\end{center}
%\markboth{AGRADECIMIENTOS23}{AGRADECIMIENTOS} % encabezado 

A mi madre Bella, por su amor incondicional que hace posible que mis proyectos culminen con éxito.

A mi padre Fabián, quien me impulsa a seguir adelante y del cual heredé el gusto por las matemáticas.

A mi Director de Tesis Dr. Hernán Benalcázar, expreso mi gratitud por transmitirme sus conocimientos.
%Expreso mi agradecimiento a Msc. Guillermo Albuja por su grande y valioso apoyo, adem´as de sus importantes consejos y sugerencias, que han sido importantes
%para la realizaci´on de este proyecto.

A Mirely Tobar, por su amistad durante toda la carrera y todo el apoyo durante la realización de este proyecto.

A mis amigos David, Diana, Angel y Felipe por todos esos buenos momentos que hemos pasado juntos durante nuestra vida universitaria.
%-------------------------------
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contenido}
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{\hfill\bfseries\Large CONTENIDO\hfill}  
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\renewcommand*{\listtablename}{\hfill\bfseries\Large LISTA DE TABLAS\hfill}  
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lista de tablas}
\listoftables
%\setcounter{page}{9}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

At the moment of compiling the following is shown in the pages of the table of contents

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note: tag [tag:latex3] is not relevant here; it is not the general tag for LaTeX.

Comment: If you look at the first pages of chapters and parts, you won't see any page numbers also. That is a normal behaviour.

Comment: Your code snippet is useless, the important parts a missing. Make a real, complete MWE.

Comment: `Here is a part of a MWE` -- a part of a MWE is a contradiction since it does not work with parts ;-). You could get rid of those `\addcontentsline` with `\usepackage{tocbibind}`, however, that does not solve your issue with the missing page numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the page numbers printed on the first page of a chapter, the TOC, LOF and LOT you need to change in your code for style `plain` the line `\fancyfoot[C]{}` to

```
\fancyfoot[C]{\bfseries \thepage}
```

You called several packages in your code twice, and please note that package `hyperref` should be called last in your case. You should rework the order of calls of packages in your code.

Please see the following MWE showing the solution for the page number problem. I  changed your given code to be more minimal and reflect only the problem you asked in your question:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside,a4paper ]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % to generate dummy text

\usepackage{hyperref} % <===============================================

\fancyhf{} % <================ clears header and footer on all positions
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{} % clears header and footer on all positions
  \fancyfoot[C]{\bfseries \thepage} % <=================================
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhf{} % <==================================== allready done above!
\fancyfoot[C]{\bfseries \thepage}

\author{John Doe}
\title{Title of Document}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\thispagestyle{empty}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\listoftables

\listoffigures

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum

\chapter{chapter two}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

you get the following resulting pages:

[image: TOC]

and

[image: chapter 1]

Comment: Thank you! I checked my code and I can found the code repeated in my MWE